# amp-html Srcset cannot have both width and dpr sources

Tags: amp-html, srcset

Think there might be a bug with amp-html. This code is generating this error on both instances, 
`Srcset cannot have both width and dpr sources`

Powered by AMP ⚡ HTML – Version 1480633190770

```
<amp-img srcset="
  /assets/projects/a/600/b-600.jpg 600w,
  /assets/projects/a/960/b-960.jpg 960w,
  /assets/projects/a/1280/b-1280.jpg 1280w"
  layout="fixed"
  src="/assets/projects/a/b.jpg"
  width="266.66666666666663"
  height="150"></amp-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [related issue](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/538) and as stated by @dvoytenko, it was a bug which has already been fixed by using commas in `srcset` URLs.

You may want to also check the given fix in [Match commas in the URLs for srcset](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/471) and view full changes [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/471/files#r41400954).

In addition to that, this [GitHub post - Validator Roll-Up](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/2595/files) have this sample code which might also help:

```
// Srcset cannot have both width and dpr sources
+    if (hasWidth && hasDpr) {
+      this.is_successful_ = false;
+      return;
+    }
```